How to free up space occupied by an old and inaccessible Linux installation on Windows 11?
This is happening on Windows 11. In the past, I worked with a dual installation.
When I opened the PC, the next step was to choose Ubuntu or Windows. At some stage, after installing a new distribution, a big bug happened and the process became to start on Ubuntu and the actual version was unsuitable. The only solution I found was to cancel the duality of the starting. Since I worked on Windows only.
But the old Linux stuff still takes up space and I want to free it.
I tried to look for it in the site but didn't find a way to make it through the command line.
Edit: The loader was Grub.
this link is very old and I don't know it it's still relevant.
I have no skills to manage alone a procedure without a detailed guideline.

Windows Boot Loader or GRUB?

"But the old Linux stuff still takes up space and I want to free it." _ Presumably you are referring to "space" of a disk drive. You need to use a partition manager.

Where did you install Ubuntu? On the main drive, in an ext4 partition? if so, 1. use bcdedit.exe to select the originalk Windows EFI file. 2. Use Disk Manager to remove the ext4 partition, making it free space. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/overview-of-disk-management 3. Use Disk Manager to either increase the Windows partition size into that free space, or format and use if for storage.

This question is similar to: How do I remove a Linux partition and expand the Windows partition to consume the Linux partition space?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DrMoishePippik I'll try your recommendation. Thanks so much.

@DrMoishePippik I tried, I failed. Is there a way through the command line to see where is the room of the Linux material and to cancel it a one can cancel directories?
